# Being notified when GPS is not moving

Tags: gps

I'm using the app Endomondo, to track my cycle training. Almost every second time, I forget to stop the time taking. And the app does not give a warning or anything, so it can keep recording for even hours afterwards before I notice. It is possible to edit the recording, but only by exporting, editing locally, and importing to webapp again. I think it's "impressive" that Endomondo does not notify of not moving, nor allows easy editing, since I know many people make the same mistake again and again. They started talking about this back in 2012, but haven't gotten to it yet.

A solution could be installing another app, that I can start at the same time as when starting the recording in Endomondo. And this other app should then notify me when I'm not moving, to remind me to stop recording in Endomondo. Does such an app exist?

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575). With the correct phrasing and details provided, you might try your luck at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).

Comment: A hint, though: Check with our [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info); I'm pretty sure this could be done with *Tasker*. For alternatives to *Tasker* (which is not free), see our [automation tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info).